# Express solutions of $\sinh^2 z=-2 $ in algebraic form $Z=a+bi$

Tags: complex-analysis

please express the solutions in algebraic form $z=a+bi$  for

$$(\sinh(z))^2=-2 $$

I end up getting $e^{2z} = -3 - 2 \sqrt 2$  but i'm not sure what to do next

Comment: Natural log both sides and divide by 2?

Comment: I think you are missing an $i$ somewhere. If $e^z$ is real, $\sinh(z)$ is real, so the square cannot be negative.

Comment: @Andrei but $e^{2z}$ is a negative number, so $e^z$ is not real. There is no missing $i$s

Comment: @IsaacYIUMathStudio oops. I did not notice the $2$. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continue your working:

Take natural logarithm both sides,
$$\ln(e^{2z})=\ln(-3\pm2\sqrt{2}) \\ 2z=\ln(-1)+\ln(3\pm2\sqrt{2}) \\ 2z=i\pi+2\ln(\sqrt{2}\pm1)\\z=\dfrac{i\pi}{2}+\ln(\sqrt{2}\pm1)$$

Comment: Complex logs are multi-valued, this answer is incomplete. (especially the expression of $\ln(-1)$).

Answer (score 1):

Use the identity $\cosh 2w = 2\sinh^2 w+1$ to rewrite the equation $\sinh^2 z=-2 $ as

$$\cosh 2z = -3\implies z=\pm\frac12\cosh^{-1}(-3)$$

Then, use the identity $\cosh^{-1}w = \ln(w+\sqrt{w^2-1})$ to express 
$$z =\pm\frac12  \ln(-3\pm\sqrt{8})
=\pm[\frac12  \ln(-1)+\frac12  \ln(3\pm\sqrt{8})]$$

Note

$$\frac12  \ln(3\pm\sqrt{8})= \ln\sqrt{3\pm2\sqrt{2}}=\ln(\sqrt2\pm1)$$
$$\ln(-1) = \ln e^{i(1+2n)\pi}=i(1+2n)\pi$$

Thus, all the solutions, in the form $a+bi$, are

$$z =\pm[ \ln(\sqrt{2}\pm 1)+i(\frac12+n)\pi]$$

Answer (score 0):

By definition,

$\sinh z = \dfrac{e^z - e^{-z}}{2}; \tag 1$

thus,

$(\sinh z)^2 = \dfrac{e^{2z} + e^{-2z} - 2}{4} = -2; \tag 2$

a few elementary and ordinary algebraic maneuvers give

$e^{2z} + e^{-2z} = -6, \tag 3$

$e^{4z} + 1 = -6e^{2z}, \tag 4$

$e^{4z} + 6e^{2z} + 1 = 0; \tag 5$

if we set

$w = e^{2z}, \tag 6$

$w^2 = e^{4z}, \tag 7$

we obtain the quadratic equation

$w^2 + 6w + 1 = 0; \tag 8$

the famous formula now yields

$w = \dfrac{-6 \pm \sqrt{36 - 4}}{2}$
$= \dfrac{-6 \pm \sqrt{32}}{2} = \dfrac{-6 \pm 4\sqrt 2}{2} = -3 \pm 2\sqrt 2, \tag 9$

that is,

$e^{2z} =  -3 \pm 2\sqrt 2 < 0; \tag{10}$

for the moment we use the notation

$r_+ = 3 + 2\sqrt 2, \; r_- = 3 - 2\sqrt 2, \tag{11}$

$r_\pm = 3 \pm 2\sqrt 2; \tag{11.5}$

thus,

$e^{2z} = - r_\pm = r_\pm e^{\pi i} = e^{\ln r_\pm} e^{\pi i} = e^{\ln r_\pm + \pi i}, \tag{12}$

$e^{2z - \ln r_\pm - \pi i} = 1 = e^{2\pi i n}, \; n \in \Bbb Z, \tag{13}$

$2z - \ln r_\pm - \pi i = 2\pi i n, \; n \in \Bbb Z, \tag{14}$

$z - \dfrac{1}{2} \ln r_\pm - \dfrac{1}{2} \pi i = \pi i n, \; n \in \Bbb Z, \tag{15}$

$z = \dfrac{1}{2} \ln r_\pm + \dfrac{1}{2} \pi i + \pi i n, \; n \in \Bbb Z; \tag{16}$

$z = \dfrac{1}{2} \ln r_\pm + \left ( \dfrac{1}{2}  +  n \right ) \pi i, \; n \in \Bbb Z,  \tag{17}$

which may be simplified a little bit further *via* the observation that

$r_\pm = 3 \pm 2\sqrt 2 = (\sqrt 2 \pm 1)^2, \tag{18}$

whence

$\dfrac{1}{2} \ln r_\pm = \dfrac{1}{2} \ln  (\sqrt 2 \pm 1)^2 = \ln (\sqrt 2 \pm 1); \tag{19}$

(17) thus becomes

$z = \ln (\sqrt 2 \pm 1) + \left ( \dfrac{1}{2}  +  n \right ) \pi i, \; n \in \Bbb Z,  \tag{20}$

which expresses the solutions to (2) in the algebraic form $a + bi$ where

$a = \ln (\sqrt 2 \pm 1), \tag{20.1}$

$b =  \left ( \dfrac{1}{2}  +  n \right ) \pi i, \; n \in \Bbb Z;  \tag{20.2}$

(20) is easily checked; indeed, it implies

$2z = 2\ln (\sqrt 2 \pm 1) + 2\left ( \dfrac{1}{2}  +  n \right ) \pi i$
$= 2\ln (\sqrt 2 \pm 1) +  (1  + 2 n) \pi i, \; n \in \Bbb Z,  \tag{21}$

$e^{2z} = \exp( 2\ln (\sqrt 2 \pm 1) +  (1  + 2 n) \pi i)$
$= \exp ( 2\ln (\sqrt 2 \pm 1)) \exp((1  + 2 n) \pi i) $
$= \exp(\ln((\sqrt 2 \pm 1)^2) \exp(\pi i)$
$= -\exp(\ln(3 \pm 2\sqrt 2) = -(3 \pm 2\sqrt 2); \tag{22}$

$e^{-2z} = -\dfrac{1}{3 \pm 2\sqrt 2} = -\dfrac{3 \mp 2\sqrt 2}{(3 \mp 2 \sqrt 2)(3 \pm 2\sqrt 2)} = -(3 \mp 2\sqrt 2); \tag{23}$

$e^{2z} + e^{-2z} = -6; \tag{24}$

$\dfrac{e^{2z} + e^{-2z} - 2}{4} = \dfrac{-8}{4} = -2. \checkmark \tag{25}$

[Express solutions of $\sinh^2 z=-2 $ in algebraic form $Z=a+bi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3531214/express-the-solutions-in-algebraic-form-z-abi#3531235)